# string erase using reversed remove_if

Tags: c++, c++14

I've string s="12300" and now I am trying to erase the tail's 0s.
So I am trying:

```
s.erase(s.rbegin(), std::remove_if(s.rbegin(), res.rend(),
                                  [](unsigned char x){
                                      static bool isPrevSymbol0 = true;
                                      if(!isPrevSymbol0)
                                      {
                                          return false;
                                      }
                                      isPrevSymbol0 = (x=='0');

                                      return isPrevSymbol0;
                                  }));
```

And I am getting this error:

```
no matching function for call to `std::basic_string::erase(std::basic_string::reverse_iterator, std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >)`
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A reverse_iterator is not a normal iterator. You have to use the `base()` function to use the `erase()` function of the `std::string`.
An you have to reorder your arguments. You do it the wrong way round.

[look here](http://cpp.sh/4s7mw)

```
std::string s="12300";
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(),
                                  [](unsigned char x){
                                      static bool isPrevSymbol0 = true;
                                      if(!isPrevSymbol0)
                                      {
                                          return false;
                                      }
                                      isPrevSymbol0 = (x=='0');

                                      return isPrevSymbol0;
                                  }).base(), s.end());
    std::cout << s;
```

EDIT: I think your code is not correct at all. `std::remove_if` doesn't break at the first returned `false`. I think it is the wrong algorithm for this task.

```
std::string s="0012300";
s.erase(std::find_if_not(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](char c){ return c == '0'; }).base(), s.end());
std::cout << s;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is simply because [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) takes a `const_iterator`, it doesn't take a reverse iterator. There's just no valid overload.

You need to explicitly convert the iterator from a reverse iterator to a forward iterator, via `base()`. And we can do this much more straightforwardly by finding the first non-`0` character from the end, and erasing from there:

```
auto last_non_zero = std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](char c){ return c != '0'; });
s.erase(last_non_zero.base(), s.end());
//                   ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

`basic_string`'s 150+ member functions are often ridiculed, but since they are there, let's put them to good use:

```
s.erase(s.find_last_not_of('0') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the reverse iterators move the bad characters to the *beginning* of the string (rather than the end) and return the position after which we need to keep the characters.

So you need to erase from the beginning of the string to the value returned by `remove_if`.

```
std::string s = "12300";

s.erase(s.begin(), std::remove_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](char x){

    static bool isPrevSymbol0 = true;

    if(!isPrevSymbol0)
        return false;

    isPrevSymbol0 = (x=='0');

    return isPrevSymbol0;
}).base());

std::cout << s << '\n';
```

Also note we need to convert the returned *reverse iterator* to its corresponding normal iterator using `base()`.